# Using map and pluck to get values from nested list

Tags: r, purrr, pluck

I have the following nasty, nested list

*Edit: updated to include `value_I_dont_want`*

```
mylist <- list(
  list(
    nested_1 = list(
      nested_2 = list(
        list( value_I_want = "a", value_I_dont_want = "f"),
        list( value_I_want = "b", value_I_dont_want = "g")
      )
    )
  ),
  list(
    nested_1 = list(
      nested_2 = list(
        list( value_I_want = "c", value_I_dont_want = "h"),
        list( value_I_want = "d", value_I_dont_want = "i"),
        list( value_I_want = "e", value_I_dont_want = "j")
      )
    )
  )
)
```

And I want to get all the `value_I_want`s

I know I can use the following code within a for loop

```
mylist[[x]]$nested_1$nested_2[[y]]$value_I_want
```

But I want to improve my map skills. I understand how to use `map_chr` when the list is a single level but I haven't found many resources on plucking from very nested lists. I also know I can use `[[` but haven't found good documentation for when this is appropriate?

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we need the 'yay's

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
map(mylist, ~ .x$nested_1$nested_2 %>% unlist%>% grep("^yay", ., value = TRUE))
```

---

Or use `pluck` to extract the elements based on the key 'value_I_want' after looping over the `list` with `map`

```
map(mylist, ~ .x$nested_1$nested_2 %>% 
                     map(pluck, "value_I_want") )
```

Comment: Ah ha! Thank you! This is super helpful but what I didn't include in my minimal example is that there are other elements in the unnamed list `list( value_I_want = "yay_1", value_I_dont_want = "no"),` so I cant just use unlist. I will update my question to reflect that

Comment: Thank you again for your help - I'd like to avoid using grep because in my real data the values are actually quite different. Thanks for helping me to pinpoint my issue - so sorry for the confusion!

Comment: @MayaGans with `pluck` we are only getting those elements that have the key 'value_I_want'

Answer (score 2):

A more general solution that requires we only know how deeply the desired values are nested:

```
map(mylist, ~pluck(.,1,1) %>% map(pluck, "value_I_want"))
```

The second pluck operates on the nesting level set by the first pluck.

This can also work on nested lists that are missing intermediate names, as often found in JSON data pulled from the internet.